# cPanel accounts unable to receive emails "host lookup for alpha.yodns.africa did not complete (DNS timeout?)"

Tags: cpanel, whm

I'm having an issue with incoming emails for my cPanel email accounts. Below is the error I get on all incoming emails when I check incoming emails on **Mail Delivery Reports** in WHM:

[image]

What I think caused the issue is that I was trying to transfer the cPanel accounts from one of my servers(**alpha.yodns.top**) to another server(**alpha.yodns.africa**). Now, I had some issues on the server that I was transferring to, so I decided to just keep the accounts running on the first server instead.

What I picked up while I was trying to fix this yesterday is that the nameservers had changed(to the NS of the server I was transferring to) on the DNS Zones of my accounts. So, I had to change those back to their original state. I thought that would resolve the issue but it didn't.

The accounts are able to send out but unable to receive any emails.

Comment: Off topic question, as made clear by the meta info in the cpanel tag.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I had to remove all the domains from /etc/manualmx using:

```
whmapi1 unset_manual_mx_redirects domain='example.com'
```

A manual_mx was somehow set to redirect to the new host server for all the domains.